# Can't read 'null' returned objects from Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is the code, is very simple:

```
usermodel.findOne({ user: req.params.id }, function (err, user1){

   if (err) throw err;

   console.log(user1.user);

      if (req.session.user != user1.user) {

            console.log('Different user!');

      }

});
```

The `console.log` returns properly the `user1.user`, but, when node.js gets in the if statement, I receive this error:

```
/root/pix/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:434
        throw err;
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/root/pix/app.js:168:38)
    at Promise.addBack (/root/pix/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:128:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Promise.emit (/root/pix/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:66:38)
    at Promise.complete (/root/pix/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:77:20)
    at Query.findOne (/root/pix/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1600:30)
    at exports.tick (/root/pix/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:429:16)
    at Collection.findOne
     (/root/pix/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection.js:975:5)
    at Cursor.toArray (/root/pix/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:159:9)
    at Cursor.each (/root/pix/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:199:11)
```

Why this happens, and how can I resolve this?

Thank's advance!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `req.session` doesn't exist in that scope?

(If you don't get that error accessing user1.user on the previous line, then it follows that v8 is throwing the error for the other .user access: `req.session.user`. Either you aren't inside of a closure that has a reference to `req`, or the request object has no session attached).

Comment: I get the error when node gets in the `user1.user`. But maybe the fault is because of the req.session.user.

Comment: If you can console.log(user1.user) then the problem is not that user1 is null (if it were null, you would get an error trying to console.log it). Try console.logging req.session to see what I mean.

Comment: I've tried it, and I receive this { cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  user: 'Mrmangado' } I think is alright.

Comment: In that case, just change your if statement to: `if (!(user1 && user1.user) || req.session.user != user1.user)`

Comment: It's weird. I have this: if (!(user1 && user1.user) || req.session.user != user1.user){ usermodel.findOne({ _id: user1._id }, function (err, user){ I don't get any error in the if statement, but I get the same error again in the `usermodel.findOne`!

Answer (score 0):

You have to account for cases where no document is returned. In such cases user1 will be null. And .user of null is undefined. So you could just modify the code as below to account for all cases:

```
usermodel.findOne({ user: req.params.id }, function (err, user1)    {
    if (err) throw err;
        console.log(user1.user); // will be null if user does not exist
    if(user1 != null)   {
        if(req.session.user != user1.user)  {
            console.log('Different user!');
        }
        else
            console.log('Same user');
    }
    else    {   
        console.log('User does not exist');
    }       
});
```

Comment: I will try it, the thing, is that the console log don't return null. It's really weird.